# How to use "standard" theme colors in my Avalonia custom control

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm creating a custom control for an application in Avalonia/C#. Its behaviour permits a user to perform selections on the screen with the keyboard and mouse. I would like the custom control to use the same colours as the standard `TextBox` control uses for its selection. I'm unsure how to express this in the "canonical" way.

My control exposes a `SelectionBrushProperty` and a `SelectionForegroundBrushProperty` as a styled properly. What I'm not understanding is how and where to specify the style "bindings" that will cause those two properties to be bound to the same brushes as `TextBox` uses. Do I write these in code in my control's class definition? In some fragment of XAML? If so, where should it go?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what any given control in Avalonia is using, you can find the [Fluent Theme](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/tree/master/src/Avalonia.Themes.Simple) or the [Simple Theme](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/tree/master/src/Avalonia.Themes.Fluent) in the repository, you will find they point to specific DynamicResources defined [in the theme](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Themes.Fluent/Accents/FluentControlResources.xaml). The Selection brush on textbox, for example, is

```xml
<Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}" />
```

You typically want to make TemplatedControls **lookless** and allow the consumer of the control to style/template it, while providing only a minimal default template.

Let me start by saying, if your custom control contains other controls, such as a textbox, rather the providing "pass through" AvaloniaProperties to style the properties of this nested control, you can just have the style [drill down with selectors](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/basics/user-interface/styling/styles#the-selector) to the nested control, any consumer of your control can do this.  Avalonia makes this incredibly easy to do, so there is no need to bloat your control with extra Styled properties.

However, if the color represents something unique that you are drawing yourself and you need to give it a nice name rather than forcing the consumer to try to style geometries and other drawing elements, then you will want to provide AvaloniaProperties.  Even in doing this you will define a simple color as a default and then the consumer can style it.  So even in this case, "binding" a color to a textbox isn't necessary, just give it the default color you want, and then it can be styled by the consuming application.

This can be done as a default value in the registration:

```cs
  public static readonly StyledProperty<Brush> MyColorProperty =
      AvaloniaProperty.Register<MyControl, Brush>(nameof(MyColor), Brushes.Red);
```

or as a Setter in the control's XAML.

```xml
  <Style Selector="namespace|MyControl">
    <Setter Property="MyColor" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Line Stroke="{TemplateBinding MyColor}"/>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Keep in mind that the above two methods are not equivalent.  The first one will guarantee a default value, the second one there will be a short period before the template is applied that the property value will be null.  This probably won't make a lot of difference for a simple color, but it's important to know if your control logic tries to use it right away before the template is applied.  However, if you want to provide different themes based on the built-in [Avalonia themes](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/basics/user-interface/styling/themes/), the second is the way to do it.  I tend to do both.